# How to extend the border-top on my nav_bar class

Tags: html, css

I know I am hitting the padding for my header and that is why my nav_bar class is not letting my border-top stretch across my page. Anyone know how to fix this short of removing the 20px padding on my header? I play more in the architect world so my HTML and CSS is rusty, but I thought a border would extend past padding according to the box model?

Here is a link to the site.

http://www.dsu-class.com/zito82/lab03/
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Zito - Lab 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <img src="images/SAS.png" alt="Solution Architect Scenarios">
        <hgroup id="headerGroup">
            <h1>Solution Architect Scenarios</h1>
            <h2>Elite Training for Elite Architects</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <nav id="nav_bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutPhil.html">About Phil</a></li>
                <li><a href="premiumContent.html">Premium Content</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactMe.html">Contact Me</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <aside>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Blog Articles">Blog Articles</a></li>
            <li> <a href="Videos">Training videos</a></li>
            <li> <a href="Portfolio">My Portfolio</a></li>
            <li> <a href="Sites I Like">Sites I Like</a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <section>
    <h2> Welcome to the Site</h2>
        <p>On a daily basis I deal with hundreds of different technologies. These technologies span the stack from
        Layer 1 to Layer 7. It was this Jack of All Trades (JOAT), experience that I saw so rarely in the business world
        that would lead me to creating this site. As architects, we need to consider all the factors that influence our
        design. Often time's we design in a background. This site seeks to open up those other areas in which you may not
        dwell. The end goal is for you to be able to grow in your awareness of technologies and abilities as an architect.</p>
        <h3> Consulting </h3>
        <p> I offer my skills around technology to help enterprises and business owners with <strong>ALL</strong> aspects
        of their business. I like to tell people that I cover all the way from Layer 1 to Layer 7. I can assist you in your
        design and architecture needs. I have a focus on large scale enterprise design and cyber-security.</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; Copyright 2015 Phil Zito</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
article, aside, figure, footer, header, nav, section {
display: block;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px black;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

header , section , footer {
    padding: 20px;
}

header {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: black solid 5px ;
}

img {
    float: left;
    margin: 1em;

}

aside {
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    padding: 20px;
}

section {
 float: right;
 width: 690px;
}



footer {
    clear: both;
    font-size: .9em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: black solid 5px;
}

header h1 {
    text-indent: 20px;
}

header h2 {
    text-indent: 20px;
}


section h2:first-child:first-letter { font-size: 2em;}

aside a:link,aside a:visited {font-weight: bold; color: black;}

aside a:hover, aside a:focus {color: green;}

aside li {
    list-style: none;
}

aside a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: grey;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
section.h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

#nav_bar {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

#nav_bar ul {
    text-align: center;
}

#nav_bar li {
    display: inline;
}

#nav_bar a {
    padding: 0 1em 1em 0;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav_bar a:hover, #nav_bar a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#nav_bar a.current {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

If you move the `<nav id="nav_bar">` div outside and under the `<header>` tag, and then move the `border-bottom` property from `header` to `#nav_bar`, you'll be all set.

.css

```
header {
    background-color: white;
}

#nav_bar {
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

.html

```
<header>
    <img alt="Solution Architect Scenarios" src="images/SAS.png">
    <hgroup id="headerGroup">
        <h1>Solution Architect Scenarios</h1>
        <h2>Elite Training for Elite Architects</h2>
    </hgroup>
</header>

<nav id="nav_bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="current" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutPhil.html">About Phil</a></li>
        <li><a href="premiumContent.html">Premium Content</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactMe.html">Contact Me</a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Aggg, I thought I fixed that. Sorry the Padding and border are meant to be in a separate #nav_bar just like you have it. That still doesn't fix the line on my end. I've changed the CSS so much trying to get this to go away that I forgot to put that back.

Comment: Misread your question. I would take the navbar div out of the header and place it under it. You'd also have to move the border-bottom from header to navbar. I'll update my answer and notify you what it should look like.

Comment: That would be to easy, you are absolutely right that way works awesome. Unfortunately, this is for a lab that requires me to "create a nav element directly before the closing header element" That's where I am getting hung up. I'm stuck inside this header element that has padding and the padding is forcing my nav element to be compressed. I'm trying to find a way to stretch out of that padding if that makes sense?

Comment: In that case I would remove the padding from `<head>` and wrap the logo and hgroup inside a new div with a padding of 20px. Should get you what you're looking for with the navbar still inside head.

Comment: I got it to work by removing the padding of the header. Hopefully the professor doesn't dock points b/c of that. I could see no other way to make it work other then what you said about moving elements.